# Changing sign in assembly (16 bit)

Tags: assembly, arm, bit, 16-bit

I'm supposed to change a 16 bit value from positive to negative. After Googling for some minutes I found a solution, but I'm still not sure if it's the right one, so would be great if you could help me. Appreciated!

eor r4, r1, #0x80000000

Comment: Use the `rsb` instruction: `rsb r4, r1, #0`.

Comment: (this computes `r4 = 0 - r1` using the **r**everse **s**u**b**tract instruction).

Comment: Note your proposed solution only flips the high bit.  This would work if signed integers used a sign-magnitude representation, but that is not the case on ARM nor any other mainstream computer made in the last 30 years; they use two's complement.  So for example, if the input were `1`, your instruction would give the result `0x80000001` which represents the 32-bit signed integer -2147483647, not -1.

Comment: @NateEldredge: To be fair, it *does* always change a value from non-negative to negative or vice versa.  The question didn't say they wanted to keep the magnitude the same :P  But yes, a trivial though-experiment with inputs like `0`, `1`, and `-1` should be the first step.  (Or *actual* experiment single-stepping with a debugger, also easy to do.)

Comment: You want to negate a *16-bit* value?  `0x80000000` is the top of a 32-bit register so that can't be right, you're only changing 1 bit outside the low 16.  (`0x8000` wouldn't be right either, if you want negation rather than adding `INT_MIN` with `eor`, but are you sure you want 16-bit values in your registers?  Normally you would do a sign-extending load from a half-word into a full register.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **r**everse **s**u**b**tract instruction `rsb` to perform the task.

```
rsb r4, r1, #0   @ computes r4 = 0 - r1
```

This instruction is available both in ARM and in Thumb state, though Thumb1 only has

```
rsbs Rd, Rn, #0
```

restricting the immediate operand to `#0`.